# splitting string by multiple delimeters in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to `split` a `for` statement in `java` by its deliemeters in python 3. For example `for (int i = 0;)` is split by the `()` and the `;`. Then I would like to have another loop that goes through the string and then checks if it has the word "for" and then it will say "You have the beginning of the for loop". Basically I will do this for each part of the for loop. I plan on running this against a java script in which it will break it down into pseudocode.  I will post what I have done so far below.I am new to python so I am having trouble with this.

`code`

```
import re
var = ("""for ( int i =0; i < 5; i++) { \

System.out.println("Hello World") \

""")

var2 =(re.split(';|(|)|{|}' , var))


for myvars in var2:
print(myvars)


for v in var:
    if 'for' in v:
    print("For loop starts here")
```

Comment: Can you show us the pseudocode that has to be outputted? How many syntax elements do you plan to add?

Comment: So basically I will have a java program that has a for loop in it. My problem is that I want to split the whole for loop and then check individual words are in it. Then if that word is in it, I will say for example this is the start of the for loop or the the loop increments and ends here.

Comment: If you're trying to parse Java source code, you probably want to build a parser at a higher level rather than a bunch of local special cases around a pile of regexes. Or use an existing Java parser.

Comment: For example, what do you plan to do with `for (int i=foo.bar(baz, qux); !checker.done(foo, i); i++)`, where there are extra parens and commas?

Comment: Its not gonna be a big scale project. Just a small project. I just wanna know how  I could change my code to achieve this.

Comment: @jsilva can you post the Java-File the parser should pass? It probably wont be only a for loop.